# How to gather information of all the EC2 volumes using ansible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I am new to ansible and trying to figure out some solutions. Can someone help me with :

1. Getting all detailed info about all the running instances of EC2
2. and find out all security groups and the policies attached.
3. Segregate based on vpcs.

I am assuming that this can be achieved by writing playbook. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is "do the job for me" question.

Comment: Please learn playbook [basics](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_intro.html) then try [ec2_remote_facts](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_remote_facts_module.html) module.

Comment: @KonstantinSuvorov : My playbook : 

---
  - name: remotefacts
    hosts: webservers
    connection: local
    gather_facts: true

tasks:
   - name: Get facts by filter
     ec2_remote_facts:
       filters:
         instance-id: myinstanceid
         instance-state-name: running
     region: 'us-east-1'
     register: ec2_remote_facts

  ec2 :
    aws_access_key: mykey
    aws_secret_key: mysecretkey

Gives me some error :

The offending line appears to be:
tasks:
^ here

Could you please help ?

Answer (score 0):

Use the EC2 dynamic inventory http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_dynamic_inventory.html#example-aws-ec2-external-inventory-script

Answer (score 0):

Ansible ec2 cloud module will help you to manage AWS platform. To get information about all the instances you can use ec2_remote_facts. To go to advance level I will also recommend to read about AWS dynamic inventory.